# mixing AMP and non-amp pages

Tags: mobile, amp-html

Complete edit:
I have at the moment small page. I am not restricted to any blogger platform. Just several server restrictions, but some of them are fixed wit .htaccess. DataURI, CSS and sprites will be used to mitigate the connect time penalties.

Will creating AMP entry page (or few pages) be considered cheating, because mainly static HTML with adaptive/responsive CSS will be served and not AMP pages?

Will standalone pictures benefit from the advertised caching if they are referenced in source, but thumbnails are used to link to standalone pictures? Do I have to make gallery with full size pictures to force caching?

Is it worth to create small AMP subset just to advertise or wait to have large content pool and many visitors?

Comment: Be precise as to what you are asking. Anything can hardly be made out of what you have written.

Comment: You have several questions here, without any code examples. Please clarify your question as to what you are asking and include examples of code, what you have tried, etc.

Comment: Well... I abandoned the AMP landing page for performance gain becuse I have enabled H2. Waiting for H3 :) I think AMP would be great but just a landing page might be cheating and not really worth it. If I switch to auto-generated content and/or have more content- i will test AMP.

Answer (score 0):

Just answer your question in title, yes you can have AMP and NON-AMP pages. You can see WordPress plugin here https://wordpress.org/plugins/amp/ , they are currently generating AMP page for each Blog Post in Single view, however any other custom post types like Pages, Archive pages, Category pages,front page are all non-AMP.